# IPV6 (web server is unreachable) and (No route to host)

Tags: networking, apache2, network-manager, ipv6

I'm configuring IPV6 address in order to validate my application in App Store (require IPV6 Only network)

This is my configuration, it seems all is correct.

[THIS IS MY NETWORK INTERFACE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nX2s.png)

[Screenshoot for nmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLHi8.png)

[IP6 ROUTE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWYQo.png)

[UFW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nneMi.png)

[IFCONFIG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jHhK.png)

[APACHE2 PORT.CONF FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt8qX.png)

But my web server is unreachable,
Ip neigh show returns FAILED

and when i try

```
curl https://v6.ident.me/
```

I GET FAILED TO CONNECT TO *** NO ROUTE TO HOST

Can anyone helps me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure to use the right IP-address?

"Your" server answers to ping and other ports than 80 (ssh, bgp and irc).

Another thing is: Don't use /48 on LAN-Ports, try to use only /64.

Also, have a look to the docs of your provider. fe80:: for default gw is possible, but a little bit strange.

Comment: My ipv6 public adress was same with my gateway before changing it to fe80::